# Getting and Printing User Inputs in HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, user-input

I stepped into Java one month ago, and have been studying then. I've come across with a problem. I need to get N number of user input pairs (key:value) to a HashMap in Java, as mentioned in below code. This gives me an InputMismatchException after entering one key:value pair. For the best of my knowledge, I can't figure out whether there is a syntax error in declared loops and assigning user input value pairs to declared HashMap. I will be really grateful if someone can elaborate this, hopefully in simple terms, as I'm a very beginner. Thank you so much for your concern.

```
public static void main (String [] arg){
    HashMap<String, Integer> phonebook = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    //N= Number of contacts to be entered by the user
    int N = obj.nextInt();
    //Getting N num of user inputs for names and contacts
    while(N>0){
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            //we need to input name and contact value pairs
            //in same line
            String name = obj.nextLine();
            int contact = obj.nextInt();
            //assigning user input key:value pairs to hashmap
            phonebook.put(name, contact);
        }
        //setting key:value pairs to display
        Set<String> keys = phonebook.keySet();
        for(String i:keys)
        {
            System.out.println(i +"="+phonebook.get(i));
        }
        N--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that, user input key:value pairs are supposed to enter in a single line like "John" 1234 (whitespace between). When I am trying to test user inputs in this format, I get InputMismatchException. Apologies for my mistake. Could you please help me out here?

Comment: By the way, indenting your code properly promotes comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `obj.nextLine()` statement after getting N. When you enter something in a prompt, there's an end-of-line character that gets added after you press enter (`\n`). `nextInt()` only reads a number, so when you call `nextLine()` immediately after `nextInt()`, it will just read the end-of-line character `\n` because `nextInt()` didn't pick it up. By adding an extra `nextLine()` statement after calling `nextInt()`, you get rid of the `\n` and the program can read the values properly.

This code works:

```
public static void main (String [] arg){
    HashMap<String, Integer> phonebook = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    //N= Number of contacts to be entered by the user
    int N = obj.nextInt();
    obj.nextLine();
    //Getting N num of user inputs for names and contacts
    while(N>0){
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            //we need to input name and contact value pairs
            //in same line
            String name = obj.nextLine();
            int contact = obj.nextInt();
            obj.nextLine();
            //assigning user input key:value pairs to hashmap
            phonebook.put(name, contact);
        }
        //setting key:value pairs to display
        Set<String> keys = phonebook.keySet();
        for(String i:keys)
        {
            System.out.println(i +"="+phonebook.get(i));
        }
        N--;
    }
}
```

Console input and output is below. You might want to use `i < N - 1` and not `i < N`, because I wanted to input 2 contacts only, but had to add 3. This may confuse the user.

```
2
foo
100
bar
1000
bar=1000
foo=100
n
1000000
bar=1000
foo=100
n=1000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.. Highly appreciate...

Answer (score 2):

You always need to put `obj.nextLine();` after you do `obj.nextInt();`.  This is because `obj.nextInt();` only consumes the number, but when you enter a number and hit the enter key, the input stream also records a newline character at the end, so the next `obj.nextLine();` picks up an empty string, and you are always off by one from then on.  Here's an example sequence of events:

1. You enter the number of inputs.
2. The program reads that into the variable `N`.
3. The program reads the remaining empty string into the variable `name`.
4. You enter the name.
5. the program tries to read a number into the variable `contact`, but what you entered is not a number, so it fails.

And for your own sanity, *please* use some indentation.  Here is your corrected code, with indentation:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> phonebook = new HashMap<>();
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

    //N= Number of contacts to be entered by the user
    int N = obj.nextInt();
    obj.nextLine(); //consume the newline

    //Getting N num of user inputs for names and contacts
    while (N > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            //we need to input name and contact value pairs
            //in same line
            String name = obj.nextLine();
            int contact = obj.nextInt();
            obj.nextLine(); //consume the newline

            //assigning user input key:value pairs to hashmap
            phonebook.put(name, contact);
        }

        //setting key:value pairs to display
        Set<String> keys = phonebook.keySet();

        for (String i : keys) {
            System.out.println(i + "=" + phonebook.get(i));
        }

        N--;
    }
}
```

Or, if you actually want both the name and the contact to be entered on the same line as you say in the comments, you can replace this line:

```
String name = obj.nextLine();
```

With this line:

```
String name = obj.findInLine("\\D+");
```

This just tells Java to read from the input stream until it hits a digit character.